# define a immediate value in runtime in assembly, it is possible?

Tags: assembly, runtime, intel

It is possible do something like this:

```
x       equ     [ebp+20]
```

I need get the value and it use as immediate value.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cant, because of the dynamic nature of the contents of  [ebp+20].
What you can do is using a debugger and look run-time at its value. Consider that there isn't one single location addressed by  [ebp+20], but it can point to any address to, depending on what ebp has been loaded with,